# Compare all elements in a vector to all elements of a list without for loop

Tags: r, apply, lapply, mapply

This is what i am trying to do

```
List <- list(LETTERS,LETTERS,LETTERS)
Vector <- c("A","B","C","D")
```

I want to know whether each element of the vector is present in each element of list or not. I tried mapply but it compares only corresponding elements. I want all combinations.

```
 mapply(function(x,y){x %in% y},Vector,List)

A    B    C    D 
TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

With mapply the output looks like this. The output I want is some thing like this

```
[,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
[2,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
[3,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
[4,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Is there anyway to do this without using nested for loop?? Also tried the function `outer()` but it doesn't works.

Comment: Providing a more interesting example would make it easier for others to validate :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps one of the following is more what you are looking for:

```
sapply(List, function(x) Vector %in% x)
mapply(function(x, y) {x %in% y}, list(Vector), List)
vapply(List, function(x) Vector %in% x, logical(length(Vector)))
```

All result in:

```
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
# [2,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
# [3,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
# [4,] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

---

I prefer the third option since `vapply` lets you be specific about the form of the output you're expecting (here, a logical vector the same length as the input "Vector"). This makes it more efficient than `sapply` which checks to see if the values can be simplified to an array (using the aptly named `simplify2array` function).

Comment: Thank you very much!! sorry, i couldn't think of more simple example

Comment: @koundy, the example was fine, but I would have changed a few values to make sure that `TRUE` and `FALSE` values were showing up where you expected them instead of just a matrix of `TRUE` values :-)

Comment: yes that would have been better. thanks for suggestion